# How to return value from a method that uses Firebase Tasks in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, task

I am looking to return value after a Task is completed within a Coroutine method using callback. But, I am getting weird execution.

Following is the code:

```
 public string GetTable()
    {
        string valueToReturn = "defaultValue";
        StartCoroutine(getTable(returnedValue =>
        {
            valueToReturn = returnedValue;
            Debug.Log("Value got back from callback");
        }));
        Debug.Log("Returning Value " + valueToReturn);
        return valueToReturn;
        
    }


   IEnumerator getTable(Action<string> callBack)
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        {
            data["userId"] = "nkjgfnmoaisd";
        }
        string tableId = null;
        var function = _functions.GetHttpsCallable(("matchRequest"));
        var task = function.CallAsync(data).ContinueWithOnMainThread((callTask) =>
        {
            if (callTask.IsFaulted)
            {
               Debug.LogError("An error...");
               return;
            }
            var result = (IDictionary) callTask.Result.Data;
            tableId = (string) result["tableId"];
            
            Debug.Log("I am being called after done :)");
            Debug.Log(tableId);
            callBack(tableId);
        });
        yield return new WaitUntil( () => task.IsCompleted);
    }
```

Expected Output:

1. I am being called after done :)
2. FNIIUSHDF (table ID)
3. Value got back from callback
4. Returning Value FNIIUSHDF

Current Output:

1. Returning Value defaultValue
2. I am being called after done :)
3. FNIIUSHDF
4. Value got back from callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a coroutine (`StartCoroutine`) does **not** delay the method calling it.

Without freezing the Unity main thread - which is exactly what you don't want usually - there is no way to directly return the value from the method. Makes sense hopefully - you can't return something immediately you have to wait for first.

You should instead - as you already did - stick to the callback and execute in the callback whatever you want to do with the value.

```
public void GetTable(Action<string> result)
{
    string valueToReturn = "defaultValue";
    StartCoroutine(getTable(returnedValue =>
    {
        valueToReturn = returnedValue;
        Debug.Log("Value got back from callback");
        Debug.Log("Returning Value " + valueToReturn);

        result?.Invoke();
    }));
}
```

So wherever this method gets called you would again add a callback to what should happen with the result.

Instead of

```
var result = GetTable();
DoSomething();
```

rather use

```
GetTable(result => 
{ 
    DoSomething(); 
});
```

---

Actually also `ContinueWithOnMainThread` should already take care that the callback is executed in the Unity main thread ... there is not really the need to start a Coroutine for it.